# Reading an array of floats from a file in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, file, segmentation-fault

How can I retrieve an array of floating-point values from a file in C? This is the code I have used so far, but I am running into a segmentation fault(marked in my code where). If you see a less painful way of doing this that would be helpful as well.

The values are stored in the file with a single space after each value like so:

`-667.0897114275529 544.6798599456312 -148.0586015260273 -323.4504101541069` .

```
// open file
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(sig_file, "r");
  if (fp == NULL){
    printf("File opened incorrectly or is empty");
    return 1;
  } 

// find file size
  fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
  long sz = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

 // store file contents to f_contents
  char *f_contents = 0;
  f_contents = malloc(sz);
  if (f_contents){
    fread(f_contents, 1, sz, fp);
  } 
  fclose(fp);
  if (f_contents){

// find how many points are in the file
    long pt_count = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<sz; i++){
      if (f_contents[i] == ' '){
        pt_count++; 
      } 
    } 

// store points to a float array
    double signal[pt_count];
    char *pt;
    pt = strtok(f_contents, " ");
// seg fault 11:
    if (pt == NULL){
      printf("error with pt");
      return 1;
    }
    signal[0] = atof(pt);
//
    for (i=1; i<pt_count; i++){
      pt = strtok(NULL, " ");
      signal[i] = atof(pt);
    } 
  }
  free(f_contents);
```

Comment: Since you counted how many points there are wouldn't you want `float signal[pt_count];` and `for (i=1; i<pt_count; i++){`? You also need to check if the pointer returned by `strtok` is not `NULL` every time before you use it.

Comment: Do note that the example input contains numbers with far more precision than type `float` can represent.  Are you sure you don't want `double`s, instead?

Comment: Why don't you use `fscanf()` instead of parsing the file yourself with `strtok()` and `atof()`?

Comment: Small tip, don't underestimate the power of `return`. `if (!f_contents){ fclose(fp); printf("failed to malloc\n"); return; }` No further checking if `f_contents` is valid is needed after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you see a less painful way of doing this that would be helpful as well.

I haven't studied your code enough to identify the source of the segfault, because it should just be rewritten anyway.  I might be inclined to do something more like this:

```
  // open file
  FILE *fp = fopen(sig_file, "r");

  if (fp == NULL){
    perror("fopen");
    return 1;
  }

  size_t sz = 0;

  for (int c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
      if (c == ' ') sz++;
  }

  rewind(fp);

  double signal[sz];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &signal[i]) != 1) {
        fclose(fp);
        fputs("I/O error, malformed input, or premature EOF\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
```

If the file is long, then it might be worthwhile to read it all in one pass instead of counting elements first (and especially instead of slurping the entire file into memory).  You can achieve such a one-pass read by storing the values in a more flexible data structure: some variety of linked list, or a dynamically allocated (and reallocated as necessary) array.

A linked list would need to be postprocessed into array form, but you might be able to use a dynamically allocated array as-is.  You would *need* to use either a dynamically allocated array or a large-enough fixed-size array with a C implementation that does not support variable-length arrays, such as MS Visual Studio.

Comment: It should be made clear that if the list of entries is too large this example will cause a stack overflow as it's using local stack allocation for `signal`, in which case the use of `malloc` would be more appropriate. Use of dynamic realloc/linked lists is a good idea as suggested.

Comment: @Geoffrey, the use of a VLA is mimicing the OP's code.  Also, because I can't help a bit of pedantry: the C language specifications do not require a C implementation to implement VLAs via stack allocation.  Nor even to use a stack at all, for that matter.

Comment: Very true, but for someone new to C which the OP cleary seems to be, this is something they may not be aware of and as such it's a good idea to inform them to prevent a simple copy&paste of this code.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `strtok()` must be a null-terminated string. `fread()` doesn't add a null terminator, and even if it did, you didn't allocate enough space for `f_contents` to hold it.

So use this code to allocate and fill in `f_contents`

```
  f_contents = malloc(sz+1);
  if (f_contents){
    fread(f_contents, 1, sz, fp);
    f_contents[sz] = '\0';
  } 
  fclose(fp);
```